# GMap.NET current marker not firing onMarkEnter/onMarkLeave

Tags: gmap.net

When hovering over a marker using GMap.NET, it does not fire the events:

```
 private void gMapControl1_OnMarkerEnter(GMapMarker item)
        {
            currentMarker = item;
        }

        private void gMapControl1_OnMarkerLeave(GMapMarker item)
        {
            currentMarker = null;
        }
```

Here is the code that creates the marker:

```
// Add marker
            currentMarker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(y, x), GMarkerGoogleType.yellow_small);

            currentMarker.IsHitTestVisible = false;
            currentMarker.Tag = iCurrentPolygon + "." + iCurrentPolygonPointIndex;
            top.Markers.Add(currentMarker);
```

I can add markers but when I hover over them it does not execute the onMarkEnter/onMarkLeave

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to set `IsHitTestVisible` to `true` in order for the marker to receive event notifications.